# Python XML Parsing - need to correct while loop

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, while-loop

Fairly new to Python.  I'm parsing an XML file and the following code returns the undesired results.  I can understand why I'm getting my results - there are two escalations in the XML for this deal and I'm getting results for each set.  I'm need help updating my code to only return the monthly rent for each escalation in the XML:

```
<RentEscalations>
    <RentEscalation ID="354781">
        <BeginIn>7</BeginIn>
        <Escalation>3.8</Escalation>
        <RecurrenceInterval>12</RecurrenceInterval>
        <EscalationType>bump</EscalationType>
    </RentEscalation>
    <RentEscalation ID="354782">
        <BeginIn>61</BeginIn>
        <Escalation>1.0</Escalation>
        <RecurrenceInterval>12</RecurrenceInterval>
        <EscalationType>bump</EscalationType>
    </RentEscalation>
</RentEscalations>
```

The rent starts at $3.00/sqft for the first 6 months.  This XML block shows that, for each 12 months (RecurrenceInterval), the rent will be $6.80/sqft ($3.00 base + $3.80 escalation).  The following twelve months will be $10.60 ($6.80 + 3.80).  Each year, the amount per square foot will increase by $3.80 until the 61st month in the term.  At that point, the rent will increase by $1.00/sqft for the remainder of the term.  The entire term of the lease is 120 months.

My results include 114 results based on the first escalation (3.80/sqft) followed by 114 rows showing as if the rent starts at $3.00/sqft incrementing by $1.00/sqft each year.

Any help is appreciated!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pyodbc
import dateutil.relativedelta as rd
import datetime as dt

tree = ET.parse('C:\\FileLocation\\DealData.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for deal in root.findall("Deals"):
    for dl in deal.findall("Deal"):
        dealid = dl.get("DealID")
        for dts in dl.findall("DealTerms/DealTerm"):
            dtid = dts.get("ID")
            darea = float(dts.find("RentableArea").text)
            dterm = int(dts.find("LeaseTerm").text)
        for brrent in dts.findall("BaseRents/BaseRent"):
            brid = brrent.get("ID")
            rent = float(brrent.find("Rent").text)
            darea = float(dts.find("RentableArea").text)
            per = brrent.find("Period").text
            dtstart = dts.find("CommencementDate").text
            startyr = int(dtstart[0:4])
            startmo = int(dtstart[5:7])
            startday = int(dtstart[8:])
            start = dt.date(startyr, startmo, startday)
            end = start + rd.relativedelta(months=dterm)
            if brrent.find("Duration").text is None:
                duration = 0
            else:
                duration = int(brrent.find("Duration").text)
            termbal = dterm - duration
        for resc in dts.findall("RentEscalations/RentEscalation"):
            rescid = resc.get("ID")
            esctype = resc.find("EscalationType").text
            begmo = int(resc.find("BeginIn").text)
            esc = float(resc.find("Escalation").text)
            intrvl = int(resc.find("RecurrenceInterval").text)
            if intrvl != 0:
                pers = termbal / intrvl
            else:
                pers = 0
            escst = start + rd.relativedelta(months=begmo - 1)

            i = 0
            x = begmo
            newrate = rent
            while i < termbal:
                billdt = escst + rd.relativedelta(months=i)
                if per == "rsf/year":
                    monthlyamt = (newrate + esc) * darea / 12.0
                if per == "month":
                    monthlyamt = newrate + esc
                if per == "year":
                    monthlyamt = (newrate + esc) / 12.0
                if per == "rsf/month":
                    monthlyamt = (newrate + esc) * darea
                try:
                    if i % intrvl == 0:
                        level = x + 1
                        newrent = monthlyamt
                        x += 1
                        newrate += esc
                    else:
                        level = x
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                    break
                i += 1

                if dealid == "1254278":
                    print(dealid, dtid, rescid, dterm, darea, escst, rent, intrvl, esctype, termbal, \
                    monthlyamt, billdt, pers, level, newrate, newrent)
```